# double quoting the strings inside bracket

Tags: regex, vim

I have a line like below.

fullname = (this is a test name);

I want to double quote all the strings inside "(" and ")".

i.e fullname = ("this" "is" "a" "test" "name");

Can someone give me a vim regex to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it:

```
:%s/\v(\(.*)@<=[[:alnum:]]+(.*\))@=/"&"/g
```

Be aware that matching nested patterns (such in parentheses) with regex will go wrong if the input is malformed. The above does not handle nested parentheses at all, and quoted or escaped parentheses will also break it. Handle with care.

It reads as follows:

```
:%s               substitute on all lines
/                 matching
\v                (with "very magic" switched on)
(\(.*)@<=         a position that follows an opening paren, on this line
[[:alnum:]]+      a series of alphanumeric characters (i.e. "words")
(.*\))@=          that are followed by a closing paren, on this line
/                 replace with
"&"               the match, in quotes
/g                globally
```

It is a notable fact that vim does actually support variable length look-behind. Most modern regex implementations do not.

Comment: It removes the necessity to escape certain characters, making the regex shorter than it would be normally. See vim help -- :h \v

Answer (score 4):

I would do this as follows:

```
:s/\<\w\+\>/"&"/gc
```

Due to the confirmation switch 'c' you will be asked for each replacement.
Answer 'n' (no) for the replacement of 'fullname' and 'a' (all) for the rest of the line.

Comment: This answer is not really solving the problem. It does the "quote all words" part, but completely forgets the "inside parentheses only" part.

Answer (score 0):

This command puts everything which is not space, tab, equals sign, paren or semicolon to quotes:

```
:s/[^ \t=();][^ \t=();]*/"&"/g
```

Please note that this quotes `fullname` as well, but you can remove those quotes manually.

Sometimes it is worth doing part of the work manually, because automating it would be slower.

Run the command:

```
:help substi
```

to to get help about regexp substitution in vim.

Comment: I think it's working as documented in the answer, I've tried it before submitting my answer. What do you mean by `everything'?

Comment: "Everything" as in "Everything that is not a space, a tab, an equals sign or a paren." In fact even the semi-colon at the end of the line comes out as quoted.

Comment: Made it more specific in my answer what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Also work for this example:

```
:%s/\(^.\{-}(\|\)\zs\w\+/"&"/g
```

And a more general case:

```
:%s/\(\(^\|)\).\{-}(\|\)\zs\w\+/"&"/g
```